SOS: how to reSync my wSol account to my sol account
I was trying to automate the wrapping and unwrapping of my sol. When I did that I successfully executed the swap but my wSol account is no longer linked to my sol Account. How do I fix this?

I am not sure what you mean exactly. But I am going to assume you meant that your WSOL and SOL display in your wallet as separate values. The reason for this is that SOL is the native currency and is used for paying for transaction and WSOL is a token similar to <>. The process of getting WSOL converted back to SOL is usually referred to as "unwrapping". You can usually go to Radium or Jupiter to unwrap you WSOL and it will be converted back to SOL.
